# (JTDS) java.sql.SQLException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

I'm having trouble reading from a view in a SQL Server 2005 database using JTDS and having a serious problem finding a solution.

The query is just selecting everything in the view:

```
SELECT * FROM encounters_view WHERE patient_id = ?
```

The exception is being thrown on this line:

```
rset = selectAllEncountersByPatientId.executeQuery();
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.isDataInResultSet(TdsCore.java:796)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.<init>(JtdsResultSet.java:134)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:483)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:776)
    at package_name.ClassName.method(Db_query_class.java:91)
    at package_name.ClassName.main(Main_class.java:36)
```

View Data Types:

```
id (unique(numeric(16,0)),not null)
provId (uniqueid(numeric(16,0)),not null)
patId (uniqueid(numeric(16,0)),not null)
mrn (varchar(20),not null)
visitId (uniqueid(numeric(16,0)),not null)
dttm (datetime, null)
apptType (name(varchar(255)),null)
apptStatus (name(varchar(255)),null)
refProvId (uniqueid(numeric(16,0)),not null)
pay (name(varchar(255)),not null)
zip (char(10),not null)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post up your SQL statement and also the table definitions? (The datatypes of the columns is of interest).

Comment: I've added the view's datatypes. I can run the query fine in the database...but when I try to fill a result set with it, it bombs.

Comment: Could you show the select statement

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely being caused because you are joining on two columns of different data type (one nvarchar the other numeric) - your nvarchar probably contains numbers containing characters that won't convert to decimal (e.g. ',' or '.').

Comment: I figured out that this was being caused by special characters in the queries parameter. The testers were prefixing id's with a '!'.